# Can't get a Spotify API key with my Premium account

Tags: spotify

I would like to use libspotify but I can't get any application key.
There is nothing in my keys:
http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/keys/

I can't find a link to ask for one.
I did log with my spotify premium account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work again now, one of the backend services was having a bad morning.

Comment: Looks like the link don´t work again. I get a 404 - Not found error. How can I get now the dev key?